# How do I generate an XML SignatureValue

Tags: python, xml, algorithm, soap, soapui

I am attempting to sign a soap request. The rest of the document is valid, but the SignatureValue I end up with is not what is expected. I learned Soap and signing over the past few days, so the most likely situation is I misunderstood the inputs or the order of operations when it comes to this algorithm.

Here's the request, minus the username/password obviously. Sorry for the chunk of code. Soap requests take a lot of elements to get the full picture:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:real="http://realtime.cbapi.clarabridge.com/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <ds:Signature>
        <ds:SignedInfo>
          <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
          <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
          <ds:Reference URI="#id-65BB4C5D722C51E896140612427983429">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                <ds:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="real soapenv wsu" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
              </ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>YIjV+XTiwlkXLG4yMhwuxXeHGYE=</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>OplmHJ6fpJNEcCwm58BIkM8r+sU6bsYS6DiRN+wtHkf4Aw0JFwHvbM/0noEFcVNWwVcfMMeHoidkCGVERNnWtt5e43ifIIyI1XxBaV/w3jastS8jgCxM9AXdfJKUm8Q+3pqFuaNnOAQnQPZ1FWUJh8hMWMtQNW5XRwP/+xpfSvI0lFUygy9VOZcjbYHLqadftkvmObDvN9Kg59oKYVuIRrwBeTquP/oJsdV/ni9Bu1deLSNxON4YtNU1JdGGnIkaZWbaMXVY+w9W6LBgLKoAZrKW6zi8NgtJRdSwFUOGA1eXcN82p69xgeoWg4GQd1bXYFu405hiNMuAQe98yg6s9g==</ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo>
          <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            <wsse:KeyIdentifier EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3">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</wsse:KeyIdentifier>
          </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
      </ds:Signature>
      <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username/>
        <wsse:Password type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText"/>
        <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">rDR41po8gfpi5g9cNpYWWk5easQ=</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created>2014-08-06T15:06:43.387246</wsu:Created>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body Id="id-65BB4C5D722C51E896140612427983429">
    <real:processMultiVerbatimDocument>
      <processMultiVerbatimDocumentRequest>
        <projectName/>
        <modelName/>
        <responseLevel/>
        <save/>
        <verbatimSet>
          <verbatim/>
        </verbatimSet>
        <limitByWordRank>true</limitByWordRank>
        <includeNRelations>false</includeNRelations>
      </processMultiVerbatimDocumentRequest>
    </real:processMultiVerbatimDocument>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My understanding is with the algorithm states as follows:

1. Grab the included namespaces.
2. Run the C14N algorithm on them to normalize things like order and spacing
3. Hash them using sha1, then convert to base64. That's the DigestValue
4. Import my RSA private key (not shown) and create a signer object using Crypto.Signature.PKCS1_v1_5
5. Call signer.sign(DigestValue). That's the SignatureValue

When using SoapUI, I get a different SignatureValue than it. SoapUI is correct, whereas mine is clearly wrong, but I don't know where to start debugging. If anyone's been through this before, help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [PKI verification across Java and Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867355/pki-verification-across-java-and-python)

Comment: @Brian Mego.. did you get an answer to this question ? I am too looking for this from a long long time . Having a very hard time. Can you please help ?

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same in Python

Comment: Sorry guys, I never got an answer. I was trying in python as well, but ended up using PHP and the better support it had.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is over a year old, but I was struggling to do the same thing using golang.

After downloading the source code for wss4j, and running their signature tests, I found that you don't actually sign the digest value determined in step 3, but rather, you take the entire `<ds:SignedInfo></ds:SignedInfo>` block canonicalize it, and then sign it.  Wss4j also adds the soap namespace to the element before canonicalization, in case you aren't using a DOM that adds parent namespaces, otherwise your signature will fail verification.  I'm not using Go's DOM and as such I had to make sure to add the xmlns:soap to the signed info element.

I don't know if the added namespace follows the WSSE spec or not, but those were my findings, and I was able to successfully make a signed SOAP message from golang to a java service using this technique.

An example of what you would sign, keep in mind spacing between tags matters in c14n, so I left this unformatted with no spaces between.

`<SignedInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><InclusiveNamespaces xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="real soapenv wsu"></InclusiveNamespaces></CanonicalizationMethod><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"></SignatureMethod><Reference URI="#id-65BB4C5D722C51E896140612427983429"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><InclusiveNamespaces xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList=""></InclusiveNamespaces></Transform></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></DigestMethod><DigestValue>YIjV+XTiwlkXLG4yMhwuxXeHGYE=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo>`